# Checking the basics in QFT notation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, classical-field-theory

In the very beginning of QFT we face the action (S) as a functional of the Lagrangian. I am still trying to get used to the notation used here, so I would like to check if the following makes sense:

$$\eta_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial_{\nu}\phi=\eta_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu\nu}\phi=\frac{1}{2}\dot\phi^2-\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2$$

(I'm specially interested in knowing if the first equality holds truth) If it isn't correct, then why is it so?

Comment: What is the derivative with two indices supposed to mean?

Comment: The middle part is not clear, but the last one is correct except for the factors of $1/2$.

Comment: @knzhou It should be $\partial_{\mu}\partial{\nu}$. Simply a double derivative.

Comment: By $\partial_{\mu \nu} \phi$ do you mean $\partial_u \partial_\nu \phi$, or $(\partial_\mu \phi) (\partial_\nu \phi)$?  You notation is not at all standard.

Comment: @tparker In my mind they were all the same. What's the difference between the two you wrote?

Comment: @Martin The first is a second-order derivative while the second is a product of first-order derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to write a short answer, because no one has answered yet. The left hand side should be 
$$\eta^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi.$$
 It is important you only sum raised indicies with lowered indices and you never sum two lowered indices together. Summing two lowered indices gives you a result that is not lorentz invariant.

The right hand side is off by a factor of two. It should just be 
$$\dot\phi^2-(\nabla\phi)^2.$$
This assumes a certain signature for the metric. If you take the opposite signature, then this expression changes sign.

Now your middle expression is just wrong. Then closest thing you can do is say that the lagrangian density 
$$\eta^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi$$
is equivalent to the lagrangian density 
$$-\eta^{\mu \nu}  \phi \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi$$
since they are just different by a total derivative.

Also, as a matter of notation, $\eta^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi$ is more commonly written $\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$, and $-\eta^{\mu \nu}  \phi \partial_\mu \partial_\nu \phi$ is more commonly written $- \phi \partial^2 \phi.$

Comment: I must admit I still am a bit lost, but I'll have this as a reference. I'll just come back to it when needed. Thanks.

Comment: Ya, I was reluctant to answer because I am pretty sure the answer won't help you that much. You should find a resource that goes over this in detail and work through it more slowly.